# Removing used elements from IEnumerable

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops

I have a collection of data that looks like this

```
| title | network | start |  end  | type |
------------------------------------------
| FOO   |    1    | 02:00 | 05:00 |   1  |
| FOO   |    1    | 02:00 | 03:10 |   2  |
| FOO   |    1    | 03:11 | 04:00 |   2  |
| FOO   |    1    | 04:01 | 05:00 |   3  |
| BAR   |    1    | 05:01 | 07:00 |   3  |
```

Here's the explanation of the types

- the type 1 is a `container`
- the type 2 is a `partial`
- the type 3 is a `single`

And you have to know that the `container` contains all the partials and might contain a `single` if the title is the same

```
IEnumerable<Item> GetPartials(Item container, IEnumerable<Item> collection)
{
    foreach(Item item in collection)
    {
        if(container.Network == item.Network
            && container.Title == item.Title)
            // there is obviously also a check on the times, but it's long to write
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I need to aggregate the partials into the container and remove them.

Considering that I have a method that is like this one

```
public Item Aggregate(Item container, IEnumerable<Item> partials)
{
    ... //this is irrelevant
    return container;
}
```

I'm looping over the collection if `Item`s like this

```
public IEnumerable<Item> FilterAndAggregate(IEnumerable<Item> collection)
{
    foreach(Item item in collection)
    {
        if(item.Type == 1)
        {
            yield return Aggregate(item, GetPartials(item, collection));
        }
        else if (item.Type == 3)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
        // I'm filtering the partials because I already aggregated them
    }
}
```

But as you see in the last loop I might `yield` also a `single` that I already have aggregated.

How do I exclude the partials from the `collection`?

Comment: Is that `Item` class have list of items as a property? If not, you can add one and store all partials

Comment: let's say that I save the partials in the container. Then what? The loop will go on and I will just have data redundancy

Comment: I see partials already filter by container (title and network), I think should add type in condition also. How can have data redundancy? if you mean about the loop, you can split collection before going to check. I will write a sample

Comment: This is video, right? You want to avoid yielding singles or partials that belong to a parent container? Or just one of them? Do partials and singles know if they belong to a container? Or is the relationship only one-way - a container knows which singles and partials it contains but they don't?

Comment: no one knows anything, sadly. The container sets a start and end, and all items with same network, title and contained by the start and end are part of it.

Comment: I don't fully understand the requirements but maybe first group on new { network, title } to coalesce all those elements? It seems you want to somehow process all of them at the same time.

Comment: if I grouped by title and network it could be maybe faster, but I would have to apply the same methods to the grouped collection. which means that the grouping would not add anything to the algorithm

Comment: Are there any constrains on using a IEnumerable<Item> and how many times you must iterate the collection?

Comment: The collection is ~4000 items. I'm using an IEnumerable because, well, it's a collection. When you read from a data source (database or file) it's easier to parse using an enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption the Item class like this

```
public class Item
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Network { get; set; }
    public string Start { get; set; }
    public string End { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Partials { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the code.

```
    IEnumerable<Item> GetPartials(Item container, List<Item> collection)
    {
        for (int i = collection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (container.Network == collection[i].Network
                && container.Title == collection[i].Title)
            // there is obviously also a check on the times, but it's long to write
            {
                yield return collection[i];
                collection.RemoveAt(i);//remove already checked item
            }
        }
    }

    public Item Aggregate(Item container, IEnumerable<Item> partials)
    {
        //this is irrelevant
        container.Partials = partials.ToList();
        return container;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Item> FilterAndAggregate(IEnumerable<Item> collection)
    {
        var col = collection as IList<Item> ?? collection.ToList();
        var partials = col.Where(x => x.Type == 2).ToList();
        var notPartials = col.Where(x => x.Type != 2).ToList();
        foreach (Item item in notPartials)
        {
            if (item.Type == 1)
            {
                yield return Aggregate(item, GetPartials(item, partials));
            }
            else if (item.Type == 3)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
            // I'm filtering the partials because I already aggregated them
        }
    }
```

It'll run better if large number of records.

Comment: this throws an `InvalidOperationException` in `GetPartials()` because you remove an item on a collection you are looping on

Comment: Oh, I code without debugging, you just change to use `for` loop or `LINQ` and return collection instead of `yield return`